# Mostrar opciones del nav dentro de margen del div container en Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4

En Bootstrap 4 se define: `<nav class="navbar ...` y la barra de navegación ocupa todo el ancho de la pantalla al igual que los elementos.
Y si definimos el `<nav>` dentro de un `div="container"`, bootstrap le da margenes laterales.

Yo quiero que mi menú ocupe lo que define el `div="container"` pero que la barra del `<nav>` ocupe todo el ancho de la pantalla.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <div class="navbar-nav text-center">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Inicio</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Servicios</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Contacto</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: a ver si entendi quieres que el nav ocupe todo el ancho de la pag y que lo que contiene el nav solo hasta donde va el container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplemente debes agregar el `div.container` dentro de la estructura de tu `nav` y así tus botones quedaran en ese ancho que deseas sin afectar el fondo.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
      <div class="navbar-nav text-center">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Inicio</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Servicios</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Contacto</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: No puedo creer que la solución haya estado frente a mi todo este tiempo.

Comment: @Piropeator muchas veces creemos que como Bootstrap nos provee una estructura entonces esa estructura no la podemos "romper" o modificar, pero realmente si se hace de la manera correcta si se puede, te invito a marcar la respuesta como aceptada para que sea de ayuda a próximos desarrolladores, saludos!